# Insert File Path Variable into Sed Search/Replace

Tags: unix, sed

I'm trying to do a search/replace with `sed` for inserting a file path into a string on an Ubuntu OS.

**Example of Line to Search/Replace:**

```
arc1.4x_os
```

**Attempted Sed Code:**

```
blendpath="/home/weather/data/arc/"
sed "s/^arc1.4x_os/'\''open '${blendpath}'arc1.4x_os/g"
```

**Expected Output:**

```
'open /home/weather/data/arc/arc1.4x_os
```

**Terminal Error Message:**

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unknown option to `s'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `sed` may help you on same.

```
echo "arc1.4x_os" | sed "s|arc1.4x_os|'open /home/weather/data/arc/&|"
```

I am using above `echo` for printing the variable for example you could use following `sed` for an Input_file too.

```
sed "s|arc1.4x_os|'open /home/weather/data/arc/&|"  Input_file
```

Comment: I never knew you could use pipe delimiters, I've always used the forward-slash delimiters.